# What kind of security risks should I consider by implementing the PayPal API on the client app?

Tags: android, paypal-rest-sdk

The app has basic authentication (with google account) and a firebase database. After authentication the user is allowed to import user data from paypal into the firebase database trough the Java SDK for PayPal REST API that I've imported into my app. Could the app be forced to import fake data into the firebase db if someone run it in a rooted enviroment with a fake SSL certificate, dns server and paypal server?

Answer (score 0):

From another [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110868/security-implications-of-android-rooting):

> Regarding the security risks for running apps on rooted phones. A very simplistic example would be, if an application caches an authenticated session cookie (or password) in an area in the phone that cannot be generally accessed by the user (on non rooted phones), then it can be accessed on rooted phones. (Loosing a rooted phone can lead to password theft or cookie theft quite easily)
>
> A not so simplistic example would be an attacker trying to run an application on a rooted phone and using maybe IP tables on the android phone to redirect traffic to a proxy (for an application that cannot be generally proxyed).
>
> To protect against these kind of threats, applications employ root protection mechanisms that results in applications not running on rooted phones or running in a restricted manner on rooted phones.
>
> There are counter applications that try to hide root capability to bypass root detection defense mechanism. They work at times.
>
> But a really skilled attacker can go upto the level of modifying the source code of the apk and using modified version of the application to suite his purpose.
>
> Hence the best way for an application is to not rely on the client side for protecting sensitive data or on the integrity of the data received ( the source code or the assumption that the application will not work on a rooted phone)

Furthermore; Google itself does not allow using Google Pay on rooted devices, A google developer discussed the reasons [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-security-engineer-explains-issues-with-root-and-android-pay-in-the-xda-forums/). It might also be interesting to know how Google detects if a device is rooted or not by something called [safetyNet](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html).